# jsp/javascript front end upload validation for 32 bit or 64 bit file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have an upload control, and i need to validate whether the uploaded file is 32 bit or 64 bit in the front like javascript.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way using jquery

```
$('#test').bind('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);

});
```

Just u have to include latest jquery in head tag of your page, as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

below is the input on which it ll show the size on uploading

```
<input type="file" id="test" />
```

Complete code is as follow:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="test" />

        <script>
            $('#test').bind('change', function() {
                //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
                alert(this.files[0].size);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you can modify it your own

Comment: Where does it validate for 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: i have given you the generic method for getting the size of uploading file. You can modify it according to your need.

Comment: How does size relate to getting the binary type?

Comment: You want to detect that if a file is iploading from 32-bit or 64-bit. Kindly clear your question. What validation exactly do you want...???

Comment: I thght my first line itself makes clear: `I have an upload control, and i need to validate whether the uploaded file is 32 bit or 64 bit in the front end`